# Draggable div to control a overflow div

Tags: javascript

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('barPos')[0].addEventListener("click", ()=>{
 document.getElementsByClassName('wrap')[0].style.right = '305px'
  document.getElementsByClassName('barPos')[0].style.left = '300px'
});
```

```css
.outter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: visible;
  width: 450px;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
 .wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 450px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
}
 .box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex: 0 0 150px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
}
 .box1 {
  background-color: #ff401e;
}
 .box2 {
  background-color: #f42500;
}
 .box3 {
  background-color: #cc1f00;
}
 .box4 {
  background-color: #a31900;
}
 .box5 {
  background-color: #7a1300;
}
 .bar {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 450px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
 .bar .barPos {
  width: 35%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outter">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="box box1">1</div>
    <div class="box box2">2</div>
    <div class="box box3">3</div>
    <div class="box box4">4</div>
    <div class="box box5">5</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bar">
  <div class="barPos"></div>
</div>
```

A sample is here: https://jsfiddle.net/jrf902k4/1/

The `click` works fine, since I want to make the `click` to be `draggable`, I found this drag `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/drag_event`  is quite different than expected like a scrollbar drag, could I please have some suggestions please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [ToddWebDew's](https://codepen.io/toddwebdev) [project](https://codepen.io/toddwebdev/pen/yExKoj);

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.outter');
let isDown = false;
let startX;
let scrollLeft;

slider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDown = true;
  slider.classList.add('active');
  startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
});
slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
});
slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
});
slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if(!isDown) return;
  e.preventDefault();
  const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  const walk = (x - startX) * 1; //scroll-fast
  slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
  console.log(walk);
});
```

```css
.outter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: visible;
  width: 450px;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
 .wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 450px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
}
 .box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex: 0 0 150px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
}
 .box1 {
  background-color: #ff401e;
}
 .box2 {
  background-color: #f42500;
}
 .box3 {
  background-color: #cc1f00;
}
 .box4 {
  background-color: #a31900;
}
 .box5 {
  background-color: #7a1300;
}
 .bar {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 450px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
 .bar .barPos {
  width: 35%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outter">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="box box1">1</div>
    <div class="box box2">2</div>
    <div class="box box3">3</div>
    <div class="box box4">4</div>
    <div class="box box5">5</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bar">
  <div class="barPos"></div>
</div>
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/x5f4q730/

Comment: Thanks for your time, it is not exactly what I wanted but it gives the idea how to do it. Marked it the right answer